# JQuery - element value after reload content using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have problem with input value which is reloaded using Ajax and its value changes after Ajax post.

When I invoke something like that:

```
var blocks_orderParam = $('input[name=blocks_order]').val();
```

in blocks_orderParam variable there is value before Ajax post.

Any ideas how to reload this value in DOM?

Comment: When do you call the `val` method?

Comment: Are you sure that `$('input[name=blocks_order]').length == 1`?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is out of the ajax callback function, then it will be executed before the ajax callback function.

Put the code in the ajax success callback, then you will find the value changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your

```
var blocks_orderParam = $('input[name=blocks_order]').val();
```

within ajax callback `success` function after value change happen. Because, as `AJAX` is **asynchronous**, so execution that statement out of ajax `success` function can't catch the update value.

**For example:**

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function() {
    // get value of the input after change
    var blocks_orderParam = $('input[name=blocks_order]').val();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, it is correct. But I call var blocks_orderParam = $('input[name=blocks_order]').val(); in click handler of some button.

Comment: @Mirek if you're getting the value on a button click, then one possible solution would be, set that button `disable` at start of ajax request and make that `enable` after response arrive within `success` function. Try this and comment if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   // ...
}).done(function(){
     var blocks_orderParam = $('input[name=blocks_order]').val();
})
```

Comment: The main problem is that value of $('input[name=blocks_order]') element, which is reloaded via Ajax post, is cached by JQuery. I still can not find a solution to also reload this value  - using chrome inspector I can see that element is correct after post, has new value